# SQLPlus: Cmd vs PowerShell

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, powershell

From cmd.exe, when I run:

```
C:\oracle\client\BIN\sqlplus.exe username@server
```

then type my password, I get in. However, if I run the same command from PowerShell and type the same password I get:

```
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

After searching for a bit and making triply sure that I'm typing my password right I still can't figure out why SQLPlus isn't working for me from PowerShell. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arg, found the problem. My username is `ops$account` and PowerShell treats `$` as a start of variable token. Because $account was null the username I was passing was just "ops". I fixed the issue by escaping the $ with the backtick, i.e.

```
C:\oracle\client\BIN\sqlplus.exe ops`$account@server
```